# Dynamic, Conditioned Drupal Webforms Select Options

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, webforms

I'm a beginner in Drupal and I'm working on a project for a hospital, and I'm stuck in some issues that I didn't find any answers to, so here is my problem:

**What I've done**

- created roles (doctor, patient, manager).
- created a taxonomy vocabulary "specialty" that contains medical specialties as terms e.g eye department, surgery department, etc.
- installed modules (Views, Webforms, Webforms term options) to create a medical appointments booking form that accepts name, mobile number, specialty, doctor, date and time.
- for the specialty field I added an automatic Webform term option to take the values from the taxonomy vocabulary.

**What I want to do**

- I want to assign doctors to a specific specialty, e.g. doctor_x & doctor_y are working in eye deptartment, doctor_a & doctor_b are working in surgery, and so on.
- when the patient chooses eye dept. in the form, the 'doctor' option is filled with the doctors that work in this dept.
- when the patient selects the same time & date for the same doctor a message should be shown: "This appointment is already reserved please choose another one!".
- create a views page of the submissions of every doctor that appears on his account (no one can see it except him) arranged and separated by day.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers, Sayed! I edited your question a little bit to make the formatting work better. Read the (Markdown help)[http://drupal.stackexchange.com/editing-help] if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: Thank you @marcvangend, It looks great now!, I'll do more effort on the Formatting next time.